# Active Directory | Times Connected to Share

Tags: active-directory, network-share

I am attmpting to see how many times each AD users has connected to a share drive. It would also be nice to see the last connected time.

I have searched for about 2 days and cant find an answer on the count. Any assistance on this would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a share in a DFS namespace or a standalone/regular network share?

Comment: Sadly, Standalone.